# KSOAP Android - ADBException: Unexpected subelement

Tags: android, web-services, soap, apache-axis, ksoap2

I am trying to implement the public webservice http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl for testing purposes in android. However, I get the following exception upon executing the call method on the HttpTransportSE object.

```
org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement getBank
```

Below is my code that attempts to access the getBank method the webservice provides. I try to pass the parameter "blz" with value "10010010" upon which I expect a String containing some information about the associated bank.

```
public class MyWebserviceFetchingIntentService extends IntentService {

public MyWebserviceFetchingIntentService() {
    super("MyWebserviceFetchingIntentService");
}

public static final String RESPONSE_MESSAGE = "response";

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/blz/getBank";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getBank";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/blz/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService";


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("blz", "10010010");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.d("dump Request: " ,androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
        SoapPrimitive resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        Log.d("SOAP: ",resultsRequestSOAP.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SOAP Exception","Error:", e);
    }
```

As I assume that the public webservice is fine, it must be the way I create my request. Probably something is wrong with my final Strings used to build the request, but I couldn't find a working solution.
Something else I tried is dumping the generated request (as you can see from the code above). This is the dumped request that results in the error mentioned above:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:getBank id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://www.thomas-bayer.com/blz/">
            <blz i:type="d:string">10010010</blz>
        </n0:getBank>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

I tried to compare it with a working request generated by SOAP-UI. Here is the working request from SOAP-UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <blz:getBank>
            <blz:blz>10010010</blz:blz>
        </blz:getBank>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I did notice that my tags are a little off, but I have no idea how to fix that. What is wrong with my code?